# How to find recursive equation?

Tags: recursive-algorithms, z-transform

The battery of a mobile phone discharges half every day. Every three days ($k =
3, 6, 9, ...$) the phone is charged $1Ah$ at midnight. On day $0$ it was with $0.5Ah$ charged. 
Determine a recursive equation in the time domain for the mobile phone battery $y (k)$ on the respective evening at $23:59h$ of the day $k$. Give $z$ transform of $y(k)$.

What I did..

0 . day - $0.5$

1. day - $0.25$
2. day - $0.125$
3. day - $0.0625+05=0.5625$
4. day - $0.28125$
5. day - $0.140625$
6. day - $0.0703125+0.5=0.5703125$
   $...$

   $...$

$y(k)=0.5 \delta(k)+\frac{1}{2}y(k-1)....?$

I started with recursive formula but I don't know how to finish it. I used delta function for the day $0$ and $\frac{1}{2}y(k-1)$ because it will be discharged by half every day, but what to do with the part when mobile phone will be charged with $ 0.5Ah$ every three days?

Edit: It is given following hint in example: 
$\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty } z^-1=\frac{z}{z-1} $

$cos(x)=\frac{e^{ix}+e^{-ix}}{2} $

$sin(x)=\frac{e^{ix}-e^{-ix}}{2j} $

Comment: How about $y(k)=\frac{1}{2}y(k-1)$ **if** $k \mod 3 \neq 0$ and $y(k)=\frac{1}{2}y(k-1)+0.5$ **if** $k \mod 3 = 0$? With initial condition $y(0)=0.5$

Comment: But is it possible to have both cases in one equation?

Comment: I edited my question and wrote hint which is given in example.

Comment: Maybe you are thinking about $$y(k)=\frac13\cos\left(\frac23k\pi\right)+\frac16+\frac12y(k-1)$$ which is one of these completely useless, and nevertheless closed, formulas?

Comment: you completely changed your problem, my answer stands for the initial version of your problem.

Comment: Yeah, this is definitely unpleasant...

Answer (score 0):

You can as well put $y_0=1$ and :

- $y_{3k+1}=\frac{1}{2}y_{3k}$
- $y_{3k+2}=\frac{1}{2}y_{3k+1}$
- $y_{3k+3}=\frac{1}{2}y_{3k+2}+\frac{1}{2}$

First you can search how does evolve $x_k=y_{3k}$ ?

$x_{k+1}=y_{3k+3}=\frac{1}{2}y_{3k+2}+\frac{1}{2}=\frac{1}{8}y_{3k}+\frac{1}{2}=\frac{1}{8}x_{k}+\frac{1}{2}$

Thus $x_k=\frac{x_0}{8^k}+\frac{1}{2}\sum\limits_{i=0}^{k-1}(\frac{1}{8})^i=\frac{1}{8^k}+\frac{1}{2}\frac{8}{7}(1-\frac{1}{8^k})$

So finally :

- $x_k=(4+\frac{3}{8^k})/7$
- $y_{3k+r}=x_k/2^r$ for $r=0,1,2$

From there it is just mechanical to find the z-transform $F(z)=\sum y_k\,z^k$.

$F(z)=(1+\frac{z}{2}+\frac{z^2}{4})(\frac{4/7}{1-z^3}+\frac{24/7}{8-z^3})$ for $|z|<1$.

Answer (score 0):

You can proficiently  exploit the linearity of the z-Transform and deal separately with the discharging and charging
processes and then add the results. So

*(note: I am using the "one-sided positive powers ($z^n$)" version)*

**Discharging**

For this process we can write
$$
y_{\,k}  = \frac{1}
{2}y_{\,k - 1}  + 0.5\left[ {k = 0} \right]
$$
where $[P]$ is the *Iverson bracket*
$$
\left[ P \right] = \left\{ {\begin{array}{*{20}c}
   1 & {P = TRUE}  \\
   0 & {P = FALSE}  \\
 \end{array} } \right.
$$
Therefore
$$
\begin{gathered}
  F_{\,d} (z) = \sum\limits_{0 \leqslant \,k} {y_{\,k} \,z^{\,k} }  = \frac{1}
{2}\sum\limits_{0 \leqslant \,k} {y_{\,k - 1} \,z^{\,k} }  + 0.5\sum\limits_{0 \leqslant \,k} {\left[ {k = 0} \right]\,z^{\,k} }  =  \hfill \\
   = \frac{z}
{2}\sum\limits_{0 \leqslant \,k} {y_{\,k - 1} \,z^{\,k - 1} }  + 0.5 = \frac{z}
{2}F_{\,d} (z) + \frac{1}
{2} \hfill \\ 
\end{gathered} 
$$
i.e.:
$$
F_{\,d} (z) = \frac{{1/2}}
{{1 - z/2}} = \frac{1}
{{2 - z}}
$$

**Charging**

The charging process is not governed by a recursion: when to charge and how much to charge
do not depend on the previous actions, yet just on the time (every $3$ days).
That is, $y_{k}$ is just a function of $k$, a train of pulses of period $3$ days, starting at day $3$:
$$
y_{\,k}  = 1\left[ {k\bmod 3 = 0} \right]\left[ {0 < k} \right] = 1\left[ {k\bmod 3 = 0} \right] - \left[ {0 = k} \right]
$$
Therefore
$$
\begin{gathered}
  F_{\,c} (z) = \sum\limits_{0 \leqslant \,k} {y_{\,k} \,z^{\,k} }  = \sum\limits_{0 \leqslant \,k} {\left[ {k\bmod 3 = 0} \right]\,z^{\,k} }  - \sum\limits_{0 \leqslant \,k} {\left[ {k = 0} \right]\,z^{\,k} }  =  \hfill \\
   = \left( {1 + z^{\,3}  + z^{\,6}  +  \cdots } \right) - 1 = z^{\,3} \left( {1 + z^{\,3}  + z^{\,6}  +  \cdots } \right) =  \hfill \\
   = \frac{{z^{\,3} }}
{{1 - z^{\,3} }} \hfill \\ 
\end{gathered} 
$$

**Charging+Discharging**

Finally
$$
F(z) = F_{\,c} (z) + F_{\,d} (z) = \frac{{z^{\,3} }}
{{1 - z^{\,3} }} + \frac{1}
{{2 - z}}
$$

Comment: But what is recursion formula before z transform?

Comment: @AnaMatijanovic: I added more details about chraging to answer to your comment: hope it is more clear now.